# .NET WebAPI Project: HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden when migrating from .net framework 4.5 to 4.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

I am migrating a WebAPI project from .net framework 4.5 to .net framework 4.5.2 and I get this error while running the project:

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

I have tried a few stackoverflow fixes for similar problems, but no success, like adding this to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

Did anyone have this problem before? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IIS check the Websites Application Pool is using .Net 4.0 and Integrated.

```
Start > run > inetmgr
```